# Access custom modules in another directory in a docker-flask app

Tags: python

I have a flask app that I'm trying to get running via docker. I'm hitting a problem where one of the modules can't import another, a simplified version of my file structure is this:

```
app.
+-- README.txt
+-- source_directory
|   +-- source_configs.py
+-- libs
|   +-- api
|   |  +-- api.py
|   +-- header.py
+-- _data
|   +-- jira_extra.py
+-- _site
+-- main.py
```

The file jira_extra.py has this top import

```
from /app/libs/api import api
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./data/jira_extra.py", line 23
    from /app/libs/api import api

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

Is there a different way to import custom modules from other directories?

Comment: I am not sure but is not that you miss a __init__.py file in the api folder?

Comment: This answer was the correct way to do it as it turns out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: That is different then your question, you asked for a module. But good that you have a solution!